# react-native Unable to retrieve params via deep link

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

unable to pass params from deep link. getting `undefined` when running:

`npx uri-scheme open [prefix]://news/3 --android`

1. `NewsScreen.js`

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   const NewsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
      console.log(route.params); // undefined
   };
   ```
2. `Linking.js`

   ```
   import LINKING_PREFIXES from 'src/shared/constants';

   export const linking = {
      prefixes: LINKING_PREFIXES,
      config: {
         screens: {
            Home: {
               screens: {
                  News: {
                     path: 'news/:id?',
                     parse: {
                        id: id => `${id}`,
                     },
                  },
               },
            },
            NotFound: '*',
         },
      },
   };
   ```
3. `Router.js`

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
   import {useAuth} from 'src/contexts/AuthContext';
   import {Loading} from 'src/components/Loading';
   import {AppStack} from './AppStack';
   import {AuthStack} from './AuthStack';
   import {GuestStack} from './GuestStack';
   import SplashScreen from 'src/screens/guest/SplashScreen';
   import linking from './Linking.js';

   export const Router = () => {
      const {authData, loading, isFirstTime, appBooting} = useAuth();

      if (loading) {
         return <Loading />;
      }

      const loadRoutes = () => {
         if (appBooting) {
            return <SplashScreen />;
         }

         if (isFirstTime) {
            return <GuestStack />;
         }

         if (!authData || !authData.name || !authData.confirmed) {
            return <AuthStack />;
         }

         return <AppStack />;
      };

      return <NavigationContainer>{loadRoutes()}</NavigationContainer>;
   };
   ```
4. `AppStack.js`

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
   import {SpeedNewsStack} from 'src/routes/NewsStack';

   const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

   export const AppStack = () => {
      return (
         <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={NewsStack} />
         </Drawer.Navigator>
      );
   };
   ```
5. `NewsStack.js`

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
   import SpeedNewsScreen from 'src/screens/NewsScreen';

   const Stack = createStackNavigator();

   export const NewsStack = () => {
      return (
         <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
         </Stack.Navigator>
      );
   };
   ```